# Why do we use data structures? (when no dynamic allocation is needed)

Tags: memory, data-structures

*I'm pretty sure this is a silly newbie question but I didn't know it so I had to ask...*

Why do we use data structures, like Linked List, Binary Search Tree, etc? (when no dynamic allocation is needed)

I mean: wouldn't it be faster if we kept a single variable for a single object? Wouldn't that speed up access time? Eg: BST possibly has to run through some pointers first before it gets to the actual data.

Except for when dynamic allocation is needed, is there a reason to use them?

Eg: using linked list/ BST / std::vector in a situation where a simple (non-dynamic) array could be used.

Comment: Question: If I enter lots of numbers and I want you to store all of them until I enter `0`, where would you store this data?

Comment: @KerrekSB That would be dynamic allocation, which is the exception to my question. EDIT: well, it doesn't have to be dynamic actually... It depends on the situation. I'm not sure where you want to go?

Comment: Hmm.. all those data structures that you mention (if only you could spell them out) *are* dynamic data sets. I don't really see what you are asking.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, I'm seeing some people use them when no dynamic alloc is needed. That's why I'm wondering.

Comment: Can you give an example? Add it to the post, preferably. (I have never seen a static linked list, for that matter.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but you didn't just find a great new way of doing things ;) There are several **huge** problems with this approach.

How could this be done without requring programmers to *massively* (and nontrivially) rewrite tons of code as soon as the number of allowed items changes? Even when you have to fix your data structure sizes at compile time (e.g. arrays in C), you can use a constant. Then, changing a single constant and recompiling is sufficent for changes to that size (if the code was written with this in mind). With your approach, we'd have to type hundreds or even thousands of lines every time some size changes. Not to mention that all this code would be *incredibly* hard to read, write, maintain and verify. The old truism "more lines of code = more space for bugs" is taken up to eleven in such a setting.

Then there's the fact that the number is almost never set in stone. Even when it is a compile time constant, changes are still likely. Writing hundreds of lines of code for a minor (if it exists at all) performance gain is hardly ever worth it. This goes thrice if you'd have to do the same amount of work again every time you want to change something. Not to mention that it isn't possible *at all* once there is any remotely dynamic component in the size of the data structures. That is to say, it's very rarely possible.

Also consider the concept of [implicit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_data_structure) and [succinct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure) data structures. If you use a set of hard-coded variables instead of abstracting over the size, **you still got a data structure**. You merely made it implicit, unrolled the algorithms operating on it, and set its size in stone. Philosophically, you changed nothing.

But surely it has a performance benefit? Well, possible, although it will be tiny. But it isn't guaranteed to be there. You'd save some space on data, but code size would explode. And as everyone informed about inlining should know, small code sizes are very useful for performance to allow the code to be in the cache. Also, argument passing would result in excessive copying unless you'd figure out a trick to derive the location of most variables from a few pointers. Needless to say, this would be nonportable, very tricky to get right even on a single platform, and liable to being broken by any change to the code or the compiler invocation.

Finally, note that a weaker form *is* sometimes done. The Wikipedia page on implicit and succinct data structures has some examples. On a smaller scale, some data structures store much data in one place, such that it can be accessed with less pointer chasing and is more likely to be in the cache (e.g. cache-aware and cache-oblivious data structures). It's just not viable for 99% of all code and taking it to the extreme adds only a tiny, if any, benefit.

Answer (score 6):

Each thing you are storing **is** being kept in it's own variable (or storage location).  Data structures apply organization to your data.  Imagine if you had 10,000 things you were trying to track.  You could store them in 10,000 separate variables. If you did that, then you'd always be limited to 10,000 different things.  If you wanted more, you'd have to modify your program and recompile it each time you wanted to increase the number.  You might also have to modify the code to change the way in which the calculations are done if the order of the items changes because the *new* one is introduced in the middle.

Using data structures, from simple arrays to more complex trees, hash tables, or custom data structures, allows your code to both be more organized and extensible.  Using an array, which can either be created to hold the required number of elements or extended to hold more after it's first created keeps you from having to rewrite your code each time the number of data items changes.  Using an appropriate data structure allows you to design algorithms based on the relationships between the data elements rather than some fixed ordering, giving you more flexibility.

A simple analogy might help to understand.  You could, for example, organize all of your important papers by putting each of them into separate filing cabinet. If you did that you'd have to memorize (i.e., hard-code) the cabinet in which each item can be found in order to use them effectively.  Alternatively, you could store each in the same filing cabinet (like a generic array).  This is better in that they're all in one place, but still not optimum, since you have to search through them all each time you want to find one.  Better yet would be to organize them by subject, putting like subjects in the same file folder (separate arrays, different structures).  That way you can look for the file folder for the correct subject, then find the item you're looking for in it.  Depending on your needs you can use different filing methods (data structures/algorithms) to better organize your information for it's intended use.

I'll also note that there *are* times when it does make sense to use individual variables for each data item you are using.  Frequently there is a mixture of individual variables and more complex structures, using the appropriate method depending on the use of the particular item.  For example, you might store the sum of a collection of integers in a variable while the integers themselves are stored in an array.  A program would need to be pretty simple though before the introduction of data structures wouldn't be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit to datastructures, in my opinion, is that you are relationally grouping them.  For instance, instead of having 10 separate variables of class `MyClass`, you can have a datastructure that groups them all.  This grouping allows for certain operations to be performed *because* they are structured together.

Not to mention, having datastructures can potentially enforce type security, which is powerful and necessary in many cases.

And last but not least, what would you rather do?

```
string string1 = "string1";
string string2 = "string2";
string string3 = "string3";
string string4 = "string4";
string string5 = "string5";

Console.WriteLine(string1);
Console.WriteLine(string2);
Console.WriteLine(string3);
Console.WriteLine(string4);
Console.WriteLine(string5);
```

Or...

```
List<string> myStringList = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5" };

foreach (string s in myStringList)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: hmm. So it's not for efficiency reasons then? (when no dynamic alloc is needed only, ofc)